# how to delete elements from both array list and text file in java?

Tags: java, file, arraylist, io

I have an arraylist which takes its elements from a text file, if I delete some elements from the arraylist they should be also deleted from the file, how can I do that?
I read somewhere that I should use temporary files but I didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is to copy the new elements in the array list to a new file or simply you can copy and replace the data in the original file for example you have a file that contains data and and you have an array list that has the same data as the file, so if you change elements in the array list copy and replace again the file :

```
class <className>
{

   List arrayList;

   File file;
  //you should initialize the file and the arraylist first
  public void reWrite()
  {
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)));
      for(Object object : arraylist)
      {
         bw.write(object);
      }
        bw.close();
  } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have wrapper class to hold `ArrayList` and reference to `File` .
And in the wrapper class you have methods like `load` , `delete` .

```
class <className>
{
   List arrayList;
   File file;

   public void load(){
      // Load the file content into Arraylist
   }

   public void delete(){
      synchronized(this){
          //  delete the content from ArrayList and re-write the file
      }
   }
}
```

I have just given high level.

You can either re-write / modify the file / create tmp file ,rename org file to .bk and rename tmp file to org file  - there are lot of ways to do it depends on your requirement and how the org file structured.